# pegar retorno de procedure sql c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Preciso pegar o retorno de um `select` que vem de uma `procedure`.
Vi sobre usar o `ExecuteReader`, porém não estou conseguindo pegar os dados que estão vindo.
A `procedure` está certinha

Como o retorno da `procedure` vai ser algo do tipo e ambos `varchar`.

### Item    |    Nome Item

dado a  |    dado b
dado c  |    dado c

Pensei em criar uma matriz de 2 por n linhas.

O problema está quando chega no `ExecuteReader` pra pegar os valores do item e do nome do item
Eis meu código

```
         string[][] retorno = new string[2][];
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_SelectContratoGestores"))
            {

                cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                while (cmd.ExecuteReader().Read())
                {

                    retorno[0][contador] = cmd.ExecuteReader().ToString();
                    contador++;
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modifique essa parte do seu código:

```
while (cmd.ExecuteReader().Read())
{
   retorno[0][contador] = cmd.ExecuteReader().ToString();
   contador++;
}
```

Para:

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
   retorno[0][contador] = reader["NOME_DA_SUA_COLUNA"].ToString();
   contador++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo:

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_SelectContratoGestores"))
            {

                cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (!reader.HasRows)
                    throw new Exception("Não há registros");

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string dado0 = reader["dado0"].ToString();
                    int dado1 = int.Parse(reader["dado1"].ToString());

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: É isso mesmo, pena que só da para selecionar uma como solucionado, vou pegar a do cara lá que respondeu primeiro, mas muito obrigado, de verdade @DiegoSantos

Comment: Quando ví ele já tinha respondido hehehe. Mas ta tranquilo. O importante é matar as dúvidas! Sem competição :)

Comment: A proposito, essa forma de escrever o array multidimensional 2 por n, está correta? (2 colunas n linhas)

Comment: @gabrielfalieri, qual array? O do reader?

Comment: O da string que pega o valor do reader

Comment: Mas ele não é multidimensional... Veja que passei o conteúdo dentro de string. Se passasse um número, seria o índice do resultset.

Comment: Já sei que vou fazer, vou pegar esse dataReader, jogar para um dataSet, com esse dataSet pego o count dele e com isso posso criar uma array de linhas do tamanho do count

Comment: Esquece, vai dar muito certo n kk

Comment: Cara, acho que não vai dar certo não mesmo kkkkkkkkkk Pega cada atributo da forma que mostrei. se não, só um ORM vai te ajudar

Comment: Ai que tá... tenho que jogar esses dados retornados pra virar um excel depois

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74642/discussion-between-gabrielfalieri-and-diegosantos).